# How to have one central location for all report subscriptions in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, subscription, ssrs-2016

We have a team of report developers and when each person tries to setup a subscription (i.e. report delivery subscription/method), what we do is that we go to the report, click on Manage/Subscription/New Subscription.

This way of doing it, is the ONLY way I am aware of. Afterwards, when you click on the Gear icon, and click on "My Subscriptions" you will get a list of all of the subscriptions, YOU as the creating USER have. NOT subs others have created.

This is really inconvenient because there is no way to view, edit or delete subscriptions created by others. How can I have all subscriptions in one place, and let everyone see everyone else's subscriptions and let them edit or delete them.

I know that subs are eventually added as SQL Agent jobs, but that's not easy to manage either: they show up as hashed code and i have to allow people to log into server. Is there any way to manage it through Report Server on the site?

(in attached pics , you'll see that I do not see any subscriptions since none has been setup by me.)

I know one workaround is to use a common user, but this is not very wise to do.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-all-SSRS-subscriptions-968ae4d5

Comment: @JerryRitcey Thanks Jerry: While this is extremely useful in obtaining all the necessary info, it does not provide my report developers any means of cancelling or modifying existing subscriptions. It allows them to see them (which is a great first step), but I wish Microsoft had allowed a way to certain individuals to manage it. Which is what my question was really aiming towards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a bit of SQL to view all the subscriptions. Here is the [rdl file](https://github.com/SQL-Server-projects/Reporting-Services-examples/blob/master/ServerReports/Subscriptions.rdl) if you want to see a report using it. There are hyperlinks in the buttons on the report. The one that looks like an envelope will open the subscription e.g. `<Hyperlink>="javascript:void(window.open('" + Fields!URL.Value + "','_blank'))"</Hyperlink>`. In order to navigate to the subscriptions, you must be setup as an `System Administrator` on the report server, `/Reports/manage/security/browse`.

#### Example Report

[image: screenshot]

#### Subscription SQL

```
/*'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Purpose:  Schedule Of Recurring Report Subscriptions
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @all_value              AS VARCHAR(100) = '<ALL>';
DECLARE @ReportFolder           AS VARCHAR(100) = '<ALL>';
DECLARE @ReportName             AS VARCHAR(100) = '<ALL>';
DECLARE @EmailLike              AS VARCHAR(100) = NULL;
DECLARE @ModifiedBy             AS VARCHAR(50) = NULL;
DECLARE @SubcriptionOwner       AS VARCHAR(50) = NULL; 
DECLARE @SubscriptionStatus     AS VARCHAR(1) = 'A'; -- Y=Sent, N=Fail, A=All
DECLARE @EventStatus            AS VARCHAR(50) = '<ALL>';  -- status from ReportServer.[dbo].[ExecutionLog] 
DECLARE @Current                AS VARCHAR(50) = '<ALL>'; 
DECLARE @LastSubscriptionDate   AS DATETIME = NULL; --getdate()-1

*/

WITH
report_users 
AS
(
    SELECT 
          [UserID]
        , [UserName]
        , [SimpleUserName] = LOWER(RIGHT([UserName], (LEN([UserName])-CHARINDEX('\', [UserName])))) 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Users]
)
,
report_catalog
AS
(
    SELECT    
          c.[ItemID]
        , c.[CreatedById]
        , c.[ModifiedById]
        , c.[Type]
        , c.[Name]
        , c.[Description]
        , c.[Parameter]
        , [ReportCreationDate] = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), c.[CreationDate], 13))
        , [ReportModifiedDate] = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), c.[ModifiedDate], 13))
        , [ReportFolder] = 
            CASE
                WHEN c.Path = '/' + c.Name THEN ''
                ELSE SUBSTRING(c.[Path], 2, Len(c.[Path])-Len(c.[Name])-2) 
            END 
        , [ReportPath] = c.[Path]
        , [UrlPath] = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2f'
        , [ReportDefinition] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), c.[content]))  
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Catalog] AS c
    WHERE 
        c.[Type] = 2
)
, 
subscription_days
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'DaysOfMonth', 1, '1')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 2, '2')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 4, '3')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 8, '4')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 16, '5')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 32, '6')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 64, '7')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 128, '8')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 256, '9')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 512, '10')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 1024, '11')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 2048, '12')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 4096, '13')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 8192, '14')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 16384, '15')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 32768, '16')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 65536, '17')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 131072, '18')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 262144, '19')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 524288, '20')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 1048576, '21')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 2097152, '22')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 4194304, '23')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 8388608, '24')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 16777216, '25')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 33554432, '26')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 67108864, '27')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 134217728, '28')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 268435456, '29')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 536870912, '30')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 1073741824, '31')
    , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 8193, '1st and 14th')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 1, 'Sun')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 2, 'Mon')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 4, 'Tues')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 8, 'Wed')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 16, 'Thurs')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 32, 'Fri')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 64, 'Sat')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 62, 'Mon - Fri')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 10, 'Mon - Wed')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 24, 'Wed - Thurs')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 120, 'Wed - Sat')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 126, 'Mon - Sat')
    , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 127, 'Daily')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 1, 'Sun')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Sun')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 2, 'Mon')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 10, 'Mon')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 62, 'Mon')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Mon')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Mon')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 4, 'Tue')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 10, 'Tue')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 62, 'Tue')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Tue')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Tue')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 8, 'Wed')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 10, 'Wed')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 24, 'Wed')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 62, 'Wed')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 120, 'Wed')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Wed')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Wed')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 16, 'Thr')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 24, 'Thr')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 62, 'Thr')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 120, 'Thr')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Thr')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Thr')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 32, 'Fri')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 62, 'Fri')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 120, 'Fri')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Fri')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Fri')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 64, 'Sat')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 120, 'Sat')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Sat')
    , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Sat')
    ) tbl ([GroupName], [CodeNbr], [Label]) 
)
,
subscription_schedule
AS
(
    SELECT 
          [ScheduleID]
        , [SchDaySun] = Sun
        , [SchDayMon] = Mon
        , [SchDayTue] = Tue
        , [SchDayWed] = Wed
        , [SchDayThr] = Thr
        , [SchDayFri] = Fri
        , [SchDaySat] = Sat
        , [ScheduleName]
        , [ScheduleStartDate]
        , [ScheduleEndDate]
        , [Flags]
        , [RecurrenceType]
        , [State]
        , [MinutesInterval]
        , [DaysInterval]
        , [WeeksInterval]
        , [DaysOfWeek]
        , [DaysOfMonth]
        , [Month]
        , [MonthlyWeek]
        , [ScheduleDays]
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
              sc.[ScheduleID]
            , sd.[CodeNbr]
            , sd.[Label]
            , [ScheduleName] = sc.[name]
            , [ScheduleStartDate] = sc.[StartDate]
            , [ScheduleEndDate] = sc.[EndDate]
            , sc.[Flags]
            , sc.[RecurrenceType]
            , sc.[State]
            , sc.[MinutesInterval]
            , sc.[DaysInterval]
            , sc.[WeeksInterval]
            , sc.[DaysOfWeek]
            , sc.[DaysOfMonth]
            , sc.[Month]
            , sc.[MonthlyWeek] 
            , [ScheduleDays] = 
                CASE
                    WHEN sc.[DaysOfMonth] IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(dom.[Label], '(' + CAST(sc.[DaysOfMonth] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ') NOT CODED')
                    WHEN sc.[DaysOfWeek] IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(dow.[Label], '(' + CAST(sc.[DaysOfWeek] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ') NOT CODED')
                END 
            --, sc.[RecurrenceType]
        FROM 
            [dbo].[Schedule] sc 
            LEFT JOIN subscription_days sd ON sc.[DaysOfWeek] = sd.[CodeNbr] AND sd.[GroupName] = 'DayOfWeek'
            LEFT JOIN subscription_days AS dom ON sc.[DaysOfMonth] = dom.[CodeNbr] AND dom.[GroupName] = 'DaysOfMonth'
            LEFT JOIN subscription_days AS dow ON sc.[DaysOfWeek] = dow.[CodeNbr] AND dow.[GroupName] = 'DaysOfWeek'
        ) sch
        PIVOT
        (
            COUNT(sch.[Label]) 
            FOR sch.[Label]
            IN ([Sun], [Mon], [Tue], [Wed], [Thr], [Fri], [Sat])
        ) AS pvt
)
,
report_subscription
AS
(
    SELECT     
          s.[SubscriptionID]
        , s.[Report_OID]
        , [SubscriptionDescription] = s.[Description]
        , s.[ExtensionSettings]
        , s.[EventType]
        , s.[OwnerID]
        , s.[ModifiedByID]
        , s.[ModifiedDate]  
        , [RunTime] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), s.[LastRunTime], 8)
        , [LastRunDate] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), s.[LastRunTime], 13)
        --, s.[LastRunTime]
        , [LastRunTime] = CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), s.[LastRunTime], 113) AS DATETIME)
        , s.[DeliveryExtension]     
        , s.[MatchData] 
        , [SubscriptionLastStatus] = s.[LastStatus]     
        , [StatusFail] = CASE WHEN s.[LastStatus] LIKE '%Mail sent%' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END      
        , [EmailSubject] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(s.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', s.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings))) END
        , [EmailTo] = SUBSTRING(s.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>TO</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>TO</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', s.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>TO</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>TO</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>TO</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings)))
        , [EmailCc] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(s.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>CC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', s.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>CC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings))) END 
        , [EmailBcc] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(s.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', s.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings))) END
        , [EmailComment] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(s.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', s.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings))) END
        , [EmailIncludeLink] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(s.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', s.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings))) END 
        , [EmailRenderFormat] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(s.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', s.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings))) END
        , [EmailPriority] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(s.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', s.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>', s.ExtensionSettings))) END
        , sch.[MinutesInterval]
        , sch.[DaysInterval]
        , sch.[WeeksInterval]
        , sch.[DaysOfWeek]
        , sch.[DaysOfMonth]
        , sch.[Month]
        , sch.[MonthlyWeek] 
        --, [JobName] = sj.[name] 
        , sch.[ScheduleName]
        , sch.[ScheduleDays]
        , sch.[SchDaySun]
        , sch.[SchDayMon]
        , sch.[SchDayTue]
        , sch.[SchDayWed]
        , sch.[SchDayThr]
        , sch.[SchDayFri]
        , sch.[SchDaySat]
        , sch.[ScheduleStartDate]
        , sch.[ScheduleEndDate] 
        , sch.[Flags]
        , sch.[RecurrenceType]
        , sch.[State]
    FROM  
        [dbo].[Subscriptions] AS s 
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Notifications] AS n ON n.[SubscriptionID] = s.[SubscriptionID] AND s.[Report_OID] = n.[ReportID]
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ReportSchedule] AS rs ON s.[SubscriptionID] = rs.[SubscriptionID] 
        --LEFT JOIN [MSDB].[dbo].[sysjobs] AS sj ON sj.[name] = CAST(rs.[ScheduleID] AS VARCHAR(255))
        LEFT JOIN subscription_schedule AS sch ON rs.[ScheduleID] = sch.[ScheduleID]
    WHERE 
        1=1
        --AND sch.[RecurrenceType] IN(4,5) -- 1 = is one off, 4 = daily, 5 = monthly
        --AND s.[EventType] = 'TimedSubscription' 
)
SELECT     
      c.[Name] 
    , c.[Description] 
    , c.[Parameter]     
    , c.[ReportFolder]
    , c.[ReportPath] 
    , [URL_ReportFolder] = c.[UrlPath] + c.[ReportFolder] + '&ViewMode=List'
    , [URL_Report] = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/report/' + c.[ReportFolder] + '%2f' + c.[Name]
    , [URL] = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/manage/catalogitem/editsubscription' + c.[ReportPath] + '?id=' + CAST(s.[SubscriptionID] AS VARCHAR(80)) 
    , [URL2] = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=' + c.[ReportPath] + '&SelectedTabId=SubscriptionsTab'  
    , [ReportCreatedBy] = urc.[SimpleUserName]
    , c.[ReportCreationDate]
    , [ReportModifiedBy] = urm.[SimpleUserName]
    , c.[ReportModifiedDate]    
    , [SubscriptionOwner] = usc.[SimpleUserName]
    , [SubscriptionModifiedBy] = usm.[SimpleUserName]
    , [SubscriptionModifiedDate] = s.[ModifiedDate]     
    , s.[SubscriptionID]
    , s.[SubscriptionDescription] 
    , s.[ExtensionSettings]
    , s.[EventType]
    , s.[EmailSubject] 
    , s.[EmailTo] 
    , s.[EmailCc] 
    , s.[EmailBcc] 
    , s.[EmailComment] 
    , s.[EmailIncludeLink] 
    , s.[EmailRenderFormat] 
    , s.[EmailPriority] 
    , s.[DeliveryExtension] 
    , s.[SubscriptionLastStatus]
    , s.[StatusFail] 
    , s.[MatchData] 
    , s.[RunTime] 
    , s.[LastRunDate]
    , s.[LastRunTime]   
    , s.[MinutesInterval]
    , s.[DaysInterval]
    , s.[WeeksInterval]
    , s.[DaysOfWeek]
    , s.[DaysOfMonth]
    , s.[Month]
    , s.[MonthlyWeek]   
    , [JobName] = NULL  --, s.[JobName]     
    , s.[ScheduleName] 
    , s.[ScheduleDays]
    , s.[SchDaySun]
    , s.[SchDayMon]
    , s.[SchDayTue]
    , s.[SchDayWed]
    , s.[SchDayThr]
    , s.[SchDayFri]
    , s.[SchDaySat]
    , s.[ScheduleStartDate]
    , s.[ScheduleEndDate]
    , s.[Flags]
    , s.[RecurrenceType]
    , s.[State]
    , [EventStatus] = el.[Status]
    , [EventDateTime] = el.[TimeEnd] 
FROM  
    report_catalog AS c
    INNER JOIN report_subscription AS s ON s.[Report_OID] = c.[ItemID] 
    LEFT JOIN 
            (
            SELECT 
                  b.[ReportID]
                , b.[Status]
                , b.[TimeEnd]
                , [LastRunTime] = CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), b.[TimeEnd], 113) AS DATETIME)
            FROM 
                [dbo].[ExecutionLog] b 
                INNER JOIN (SELECT [ReportID], MAX([TimeEnd]) AS [TimeEnd] FROM [dbo].[ExecutionLog] GROUP BY [ReportID]) a ON b.[ReportID] = a.[ReportID] AND b.[TimeEnd] = a.[TimeEnd]
            GROUP BY
                  b.[ReportID]
                , b.[Status]
                , b.[TimeEnd]
            )AS el ON el.[ReportID] = c.[ItemID]
    LEFT JOIN report_users AS urc ON c.[CreatedById] = urc.[UserID] 
    LEFT JOIN report_users AS urm ON c.[ModifiedById] = urm.[UserID] 
    LEFT JOIN report_users AS usc ON s.[OwnerID] = usc.[UserID] 
    LEFT JOIN report_users AS usm ON s.[ModifiedByID] = usm.[UserID] 
WHERE 
    1=1
    AND c.[Type] = 2
    AND (@all_value IN (@ReportFolder) OR c.[ReportFolder] IN(@ReportFolder))
    AND (@all_value IN (@ReportFolder) OR CHARINDEX(@ReportFolder, c.[ReportPath]) > 0)
    AND (@all_value IN(@ReportName) OR c.[Name] IN(@ReportName))
    AND (@all_value IN(@EventStatus) OR el.[Status] IN(@EventStatus))
    AND (@all_value IN(@Current) OR CASE WHEN s.[ScheduleEndDate] IS NULL THEN 'Current' WHEN s.[ScheduleEndDate] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Non Current' END = @Current)
    AND (@all_value IN(@SubscriptionStatus) OR s.[SubscriptionLastStatus] LIKE '%' + @SubscriptionStatus + '%')
    AND (s.[LastRunTime] >= @LastSubscriptionDate OR @LastSubscriptionDate IS NULL) 
    AND 
        (
            (SUBSTRING(s.[ExtensionSettings], LEN('<Name>TO</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>TO</Name><Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings]), CHARINDEX('</Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings], CHARINDEX('<Name>TO</Name><Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings]) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>TO</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>TO</Name><Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings])))
            LIKE '%' + @EmailLike + '%' OR @EmailLike IS NULL
        )
        OR
        ( 
            CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings]) 
                WHEN 0 THEN '' 
                ELSE SUBSTRING(s.[ExtensionSettings], LEN('<Name>CC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings]), CHARINDEX('</Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings], CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings]) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>CC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings]))) 
            END 
        LIKE '%' + @EmailLike + '%'
        )
        OR 
        (
            CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings]) 
                WHEN 0 THEN '' 
                ELSE SUBSTRING(s.[ExtensionSettings], LEN('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings]), CHARINDEX('</Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings], CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings]) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', s.[ExtensionSettings]))) 
            END 
        LIKE '%' + @EmailLike + '%')
        )
```

Comment: Thanks aduguid for this great answer. While this is extremely useful in obtaining all the necessary info, it does not provide my report developers any means of cancelling or modifying existing subscriptions. It allows them to see them (which is a great first step), but I wish Microsoft had allowed a way to certain individuals to manage it.

Comment: There are hyperlinks in the buttons on the report. The one that looks like an envelope will open the subscription.

Comment: That link actually does not work, do you think it's because the subscription was created by (and therefore can only be managed by) another user? Not sure, I tried to type up the hyperlink in my browser to see if it works, but it didn't.

Comment: The report itself works perfectly: all fields populated and correctly. I haven't run the query yet, but will do so shortly!

Comment: I was able to navigate to an end-user's subscription from the hyperlink in the report. Are you setup as an `System Administrator` on the report server? `/Reports/manage/security/browse`

Comment: You are a genius: /Reports/manage/security/browse did it! Thank you so much

Comment: that's awesome, glad I could help :)  You may like my SSRS project on [GitHub](https://github.com/SQL-Server-projects/Reporting-Services-examples)